# Low latency wireless trigger

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy, trigger

I am working on a project consisting of a sensor and receiver connected via Bluetooth 5.2. When the sensor receives a start signal from the receiver, it will begin sampling readings at ~10kHz and storing them to a buffer. After a few seconds, once it has filled the buffer, readings will stop and it will then slowly transfer the data to the receiver for processing.

I need to figure out how to measure the latency between when the receiver sends the start signal and when the sensor receives it. The obvious choice would be to send a notification via BT, but the latency here would be variable and far too large. I would need something faster than ~50µs

The sensor and receiver are in close proximity (<30cm) but in an extremely hot and vibrating environment. There is no possibility to occasionally synchronize their clocks physically. PCB space and battery capacity is limited on the sensor, but not on the receiver.

Is there some type of IC with this dedicated purpose? Something with an antenna connection and trigger in / trigger out logic signal?

I have some experience with microcontroller design but little with RF design.

Comment: What are the solutions you have thought of yourself, and what are the pro's/cons?

Comment: Why don't you add some firmware that calibrates the delay time. You could initiate a single shot test that instructs the sensor to transmit back a response immediately. Measure the time delay from initiating the test to getting back an immediate response and divide it by 2 to get an estimate of the one-way time delay.

Comment: @Ananas_hoi, the only solution I thought of so far (besides from the RF trigger) was what _andyaka_ mentioned. I did test it briefly and found a two way delay of ~20ms (dependent on BT connection settings). I think the issue will be that the one-way delay is not exactly half of the total. I'll try looking again at this and maybe taking some measurements with a scope to see how they compare to the measured values

Comment: Is optical data transmission an option? "50µs" and "BT" are almost opposites.

Comment: your description is a bit confusing (terminology - it sounds like your "receiver" is actually a transmitter at least sometimes). But anyway. Assuming you are in control of firmware either end, why not simply generate a test pules when the start signal is sent, and when it is received (by the receiver which I think you are calling the sensor ...) and simply observer both signals on a scope?

Comment: @rdtsc, optical is not possible. The sensor moves too much to maintain LOS to the receiver.

Comment: @danmcb The sensor is a BT peripheral/slave and the receiver is central/master (microcontrollers are EFR32MG22). BT packets therefore go in both directions, but the bulk of data goes from the slave to the master. I just now did a test of the 1-way delay from sending a notification from the master to the slave, the time was 2.22ms +-0.01ms with the BT connection settings configured to the shortest interval and no connection skips. This length of delay is fine as long as it is constant

Comment: _"I would need something faster than ~50µs"_ - Why?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Maybe I worded that poorly, the sensor needs to start measuring soon after the trigger is sent, preferably as fast as possible, but a few ms is fine too. The variation in the delay must be _smaller than 50µs_. When we are post processing the 10kHz data samples, we need to line it up to other measurements taken from non-wireless sensors